# change a usb notification(alert) sound

Tags: usb, sound, notification

How can I change the default USB sound notification? I.e. when I inject/eject a device.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu plays `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/device-added.oga` when a new device is inserted and this `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/device-removed.oga` when it is removed. So you may just replace these 2 files with any you want to use for this.

As one way to achieve this:

You can rename these 2 files with following commands in terminal :

```
$ sudo mv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/device-added.oga /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/device-added_old.oga

$ sudo mv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/device-removed.oga /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/device-removed_old.oga
```

And copy another sounds from the same folder in replace:

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/service-login.oga /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/device-added.oga

$ sudo cp /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/service-logout.oga /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/device-removed.oga
```

Then test by connecting your USB device.